# Write a recurrence relation for this modified Quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, relation, recurrence

In a modified quicksort, you partition randomly on odd levels of recursive calls and on even levels you partition on the largest element. How do you write a recurrence relation for exactly how many comparisons quicksort will do?

Comment: *Exactly* sounds a little weird when you consider a random variable ?!

Comment: Can you provide the recurrence relation for the case of *ordinary* Quicksort ?

Comment: Yes. T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + (n-1) for average case.

Comment: Then it suffices to add a term n-1 to find the largest element, then another term n-1 to perform the partition with this pivot, and replace n by n-1, as the partition will just leave the largest element apart. T(n)=2(n-1)+T((n-1)/4)+T(3(n-1)/4)+(n-2).